# How to generate spatial weight matrix in python script?

Tags: python, arcgis, arcpy

I need to create spatial weights matrices for different point shapefiles，so I tried to batch process in stand-alone Python script. Here is the example code exported from the ModelBuilder in the ArcGIS 10.2 software.

```
import arcpy
test_shp = "D:\\My Documents\\ArcGIS\\test.shp"
tset_swm = "D:\\My Documents\\ArcGIS\\tset.swm"
arcpy.GenerateSpatialWeightsMatrix_stats(test_shp, "MyID", tset_swm,
                                     "K_NEAREST_NEIGHBORS", "EUCLIDEAN",
                                     "1", "", "4", "ROW_STANDARDIZATION",
                                     "", "", "", "")
```

The problem here is that there are no output files or messages. And interestingly, when I add

```
print "hello world"
```

After the code execution, it should print a string "hello world" on the console, but there is no such output either!

Could anyone explain me what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix this?

Comment: Did you start by checking if the files are being passed properly? And if they are in the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong here. But isn't tset_swm in your code the output you are looking for? That is the output spatial weight matrix you generated based on your input shapefile.

Comment: Thank you. I found that it was ok when I uninstalled the matplotlib. I don't know why.